# How to create a watchdog on a program in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know is it even possible to create a watchdog on a program,
I am trying to do Discrete event simulation to simulate a functioning machine,
the problem is, once I inspect my machine at let's say time = 12 (inspection duration is 2 hours lets say) if the event failure is at 13-time units) there is no way that it can be because I am "busy inspecting"
so is there a sort of "watchdog" to constantly test if the value of a variable reached a certain limit to stop doing what the program is doing,
Here is my inspection program

```
def machine_inspection(tt, R, Dpmi, Dinv, FA, TRF0, Tswitch, Trfn):

End = 0
TPM = 0
logging.debug(' cycle time %f' % tt)

TRF0 = TRF0 - Dinv
Tswitch = Tswitch - Dinv
Trfn = Trfn - Dinv
if R == 0:




if falsealarm == 1:
    FA += 1

else:

    tt = tt + Dpmi

    TPM = 1
    End = 1

return (tt, End, R, TPM, FA, TRF0, Trfn, Tswitch)
```

Thank you very much!

basically you can't be inspecting during x time if tt + x will be superior to the time to failure TRF0 or Trfn

Comment: Any ideas ? it would be much appreciated